# 'No module named webtest' error in Google App Engine after pip install webtest

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webtest

I am getting this error, when I try to run gaeunit on my development server with webtest.

```
    No module named webtest Status: 404 Not Found Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Length: 23 No module named webtest
```

I am running the test from this Google App Engine doc, using gae unit.

https://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting

The test works fine when I'm doing regular unit testing.

Is there an extra hoop I have to jump through? I'm using Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

All 3rd party libs not included as part of the SDK must be installed locally in your project.

pip install will install locally on your machine however the SDK runs a sandbox that emulates the production runtime.  Everything has to be copied or linked into your project so it can be deployed.

If you do a bit of searching this type of question (though not specific to your library) is asked every few days.

You should read the docs - especially the bit about the sandbox

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_sandbox